# Is this a bug of gcc preprocessor?

Tags: gcc, c-preprocessor

```
#define BINARY_TREE_PARENT_CORRECT(son, parent) ((son) ? (son->parent == parent) : 1)
```

It turns out that the `parent` in `son->parent` which means a struct member will also be replaced by the `parent` in `son, parent`.

The gcc version is `4.1.2`.

Do you think it's a bug or expected behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior is correct. All unquoted occurrences of *parent* are substituted. The preprocessor does not try to guess what you mean. It just replaces what you say.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior. The preprocessor does not know C's syntax (except when evaluating the controlling expression in an `#if`) -- it just replaces tokens.

Answer (score 1):

Easy fix: Change the parameter name to be different from your element name.

```
#define BINARY_TREE_PARENT_CORRECT(son, par) ((son) ? (son->parent == par) : 1)
```

cpp won't match par against parent, so you'll get the behaviour you expect.